# Eclipse does not start on Windows 7

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7

Suddenly Eclipse today has decided to stop working. The last thing I did was close all perspectives and close Eclipse.

When loading eclipse from the command prompt, using: "eclipse.exe -clean" the splash screen loads for a split second then exits.

When I run the command: eclipsec -consoleLog -debug it results in the following output:

```
Start VM: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms4096m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Djava.class.path=d:\devtools\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.
0.v20130327-1440.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash d:\devtools\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.3.0.v20130605-20
00\splash.bmp
-launcher d:\devtools\eclipse\eclipsec.exe
-name Eclipsec
--launcher.library d:\devtools\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win
32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130521-0416\eclipse_1503.dll
-startup d:\devtools\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v201303
27-1440.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
-consoleLog
-debug
-vm C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_37/bin\..\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms4096m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Djava.class.path=d:\devtools\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.
0.v20130327-1440.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified
```

Checking Task Manager shows no Java process running and both the CPU and memory usage are very low.
I have tried:

- Re-installing Eclipse
- Re-starting my machine

But running eclipsec -consoleLog -debug from the command prompt still results in the issue:
    **Error occurred during initialization of VM
    Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified**

Comment: It does not look like the "The last thing you did was close all perspectives and close Eclipse". At the very least I suspect that you edited eclipse.ini The errors are probably referring to `-Xms4096m
-Xmx4096m
` and
`-os win32
-ws win32
`
Heap size over 1.5GB was not allowed/usable on 32 bit architecture

Comment: "win32" is just the reference to the OS and windowing system. It's a 64-bit Eclipse due to the arch option being for x86_64, so the values are not only too large ("reinstalling" Eclipse should have reset the eclipse.ini back to the original values--which aren't to *start* with a heap of 4GB). It says the numbers are incompatible, so try changing them.

Comment: Maybe the heapsize is too big. Try to modify the .ini, make -Xms512M & -Xmx1024M